# Can't install gwt developer plugin for IE 7 or 8

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, plugins

I want to install gwt developer plugin for IE (I already installed it on chrome and firefox without any problem).
When i want to install it for IE7 (on both vista with sp2 & windows server 2008 with sp2), it says that plugin installed sucessfully, but it does not work & nothing adds under add-ons section.
I upgraded my ie to latest 8 version & even installed google optimized version of IE8, but it couldn't help me.
Any idea ?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem on IE8 winxp sp2 behind a corporate firewall. The plugin tells me it installs successfully but it does not work. Any news on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem on IE8 windows XP, where it said it installed successfully. But it still showed the install message in the browser (and not the actual application).

I figured out why this was not working for me, and the root cause was that the network administration login routine apparently had created two profiles for me:

`C:\Documents and Settings\g43899` (outdated profile location) and

`C:\Documents and Settings\g43899.ND60A600` (new profile location)

Before I explain further, have a look at the suggestions on the [GWT defect list, issue 4358](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4358):

> 2. Is the following registry key installed: 
>      HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1D6156B6-002B-49E7-B5CA-C138FB843B4E}?
>      If so, what  are its subkeys and
>      values?
> 3. What happens when you run "regsvr32.exe oophm.dll"? Can you try
>      running  "regsvr32.exe /u oophm.dll"
>      and then "regsvr32.exe oophm.dll"?

On my machine, the registry key did not exist. Furthermore, I got an alertbox error when running command `regsvr32.exe oophm.dll`:

```
LoadLibrary("oophm.dll") failed - The specified module could not be found.
```

I was able to locate the DLL file to the first folder at

`C:\Documents and Settings\g43899\Application Data\Google\Developer Plugin\IE\oophm.dll`

But as this location was related to the outdated profile, I did the following

1. Moved folder from `Application Data\Google\Developer Plugin` into the new profile location.
2. Ran `regsvr32.exe "%APPDATA%\Google\Developer Plugin\IE\oophm.dll"`

After that command, I could actually see the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{1D6156B6-002B-49E7-B5CA-C138FB843B4E}`. Now everything suddently worked. Hope this can help you.

I am adding the [full contents of ´HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{1D6156B6-002B-49E7-B5CA-C138FB843B4E}`](http://gist.github.com/408680) in case you need it.

Comment: A clean install of Windows 7, on Parallels 6 hosted by MacOSX 10.5.8, has put the oophm.dll in a slightly different place: C:\regsvr32.exe "C:\Documents and Settings\jason\AppData\Roaming\Google\Google Web Toolkit\Developer Plugin\IE\Win32\oophm.dll"

Answer (score 1):

Most users trying to install the GWT devmode plugin for IE8 on Windows 7 (Vista) 32-bit were able to use the following script from a command line (replace "Foo" with your Windows User Name):

regsvr32.exe "C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Google\Google Web Toolkit\Developer Plugin\IE\oophm.dll"

Users trying to install for IE9 will not be able to install unless they add a specification to the doctype to force IE9 to render as IE8, per this post from Google...

http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/12/support-for-gwt-dev-mode-in-ie-9.html

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too. In my case the error code was: 1612.

The problem's cause was, that after my windows user profile was broken, I renamed it and downloaded all my data from the server into the new user profile location.

To solve this issue I did the following steps:

* First I uninstalled the old GWT Dev Plugin for IE in Control Panel -> Add/Remove Software

* As the user profile was stored in a new location i manually had to specify the location of file gwt-dev-plugin-x86.msi in the new user profile

* Finally I opened http://gwt.google.com/samples/MissingPlugin/MissingPlugin.html in IE and installed the plugin again successfully

Hope it helps :=)

Answer (score 0):

This guide seems outdatet:

OS: Windows Vista 32
IE: Version 8

I did the installation process (addon/plugin) 5 times and there is no "oophm.dll" file anywhere on my hard drives. Additionally, I was able to install the plugin for Chrome and Firefox with ease.