# Troublshooting guide for GWT plugin

Tags: gwt, dev-mode

When I try to use the GWT dev mode plugin for ie 8 on Windows Vista I continually see the prompt to install the plugin. [image]

After running the plugin I still always see this page.  Does anybody know of how to troubleshoot something like this?

Answer (score 2):

See this : [Can't install gwt developer plugin for IE 7 or 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778913/cant-install-gwt-developer-plugin-for-ie-7-or-8)

Manually running regsvr32.exe oophm.dll fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

What GWT version are you running?
Try to install the plugin from here:
http://gwt.google.com/samples/MissingPlugin/MissingPlugin.html

Comment: Maybe you have some old version of the plugin installed and this is causing the problem. Use the following steps to uninstall it:<br><br>1. Got to the Windows "Control Panel"<br>2. Select "Add/Remove Programs"<br>3. Select "Google Web Toolkit Developer Plugin for IE"<br>4. Click "Uninstall"<br>br>Then open the Internet Explorer and try to install the plugin from http://gwt.google.com/samples/MissingPlugin

Comment: I tried this it also has no effect. http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_frm/thread/1153d41c8d33129d