# IE error while accessing the page?

Tags: gwt

I have GWT application. i am using IE8. when i try to access the page in hosted mode, i am getting below error. how to resolve it?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IE6, IE7, IE8 has many bugs. 
Try to compile your project in "Pretty" or "Detailed" javascript and look line where is error. 
Then try to find in google this method. If you're lucky, you find solution. 
It has helped me several times. But sometimes the errors GWT in IE are not resolved.

Comment: it did not install gwt plugin for IE properly..is it possible to install manually? Thanks!

Comment: @user1016403 Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778913/cant-install-gwt-developer-plugin-for-ie-7-or-8